# Add image to textview from an external/internal url

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, picasso

I want to know how to add an image to an `TextView` from an internal and external URL.

Say I have an URL `https://www.example.com/img/img.jpg` using `picasso` I can easily do `Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);`

But how do I use it in case of `TextView` ?

Comment: Do you mean like a background?

Comment: How did you want to add the image to the `TextView`? `setCompoundDrawables()`? `ImageSpan`? A background image, as Malik suggests? Something else?

Comment: Ya anything I just want the image to be visible in the textview  @malikbrahimi

Comment: @commonsware how do I set it??

Comment: I didn't get you @a.l

Comment: @Ohmyholy it was just a message to explain what I edited in your question.

Comment: @Ohmyholy: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Editing posts to improve them is encouraged on this website, don't ask users not to not do it. And I can't answer to this question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.

Either use an `ImageView` and a `TextView` inside of a `RelativeLayout` or use an `ImageView` and a `TextView`, where in first place the `ImageView.visiblity` is gone and changes to visible due download and the `textView.visiblity` is is visible in first place and changes to gone due download.

Maybe for clarification:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Picasso.withContext(context).download(...).into(imageView).etc();
        textView.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
        imageView.setVvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yo,  I hit in mah brain that too. Thanks that's better option rather than going in complex process of adding image in textview.